# Knockout-Kendo.js: Set the width and height of kendoui tabstrip

Tags: kendo-ui

I am using RPNiemeyer`s Knockout-Kendo.js library. I have a kendoui tabstrip. I looked through the kendoui documentation and was not able to find how to set the width and height of the tabstrip. In my case I want to set the heigth of the tabstrip as the heigth of browser view. In the moment it is resizing every tab considering the content in it.

Here is jsfiddle.net sample from the Knockout-Kendo.js oficial page:

http://jsfiddle.net/GQqwY/5/

Any help with working example will be greatly appreciated. Thank You!

EDIT: one way I found to do this is to set the heigth on every div of the tabstrip

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've got the right idea to set the height using css.  Typically I would handle a scenario like this by utilizing the classes that are rendered on the html elements by kendo.  You could do something like this:

```
<style>
  .k-tabstrip-items .k-link 
  {
    height:40px; /* whatever height you want */
    width:100px;
  }​
</style>
```

Here's an updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/GQqwY/7/

Comment: "as the heigth of browser view" - so you may want to try percent instead of pixels. Just a thought, good answer.